# Picture naming with attributes of the corresponding layer

Tags: qfield

I am trying to add controls (layers without geometry) to control objects (point layers). For this, I take several images, too.
Now I try to name the images with attributes of the corresponding control (ueber_ent_kon, uuid = kon_uudi)

I have three layers:

1. 'objekte' (id, ..., geom)
2. 'ueber_ent_kon' (id, ob_id, kz_anlage, nam_anlage, uuid, ....)
3. 'bilder' (id, kon_uuid, besch,...)

My try does not work:

Images -> 'Layer properties'>'qfield'>'photo_naming'

```
'DCIM/'|| 

 attribute( 
 get_feature(
    'ueber_ent_kon_034e0ec4_8f93_4674_80d1_91b5d3ce8671',
    'uuid',"kon_uuid" ),'kz_anlage')
||'_'||
 attribute( 
 get_feature(
    'ueber_ent_kon_034e0ec4_8f93_4674_80d1_91b5d3ce8671',
    'uuid',"kon_uuid" ),'nam_anlage')
||'_'||
 attribute( 
 get_feature(
    'ueber_ent_kon_034e0ec4_8f93_4674_80d1_91b5d3ce8671',
    'uuid',"kon_uuid" ),'timestamp')
||'_'||
"beschreibung"||    '.jpg'
```

The generated name is:
CMD/JPEG_'timestamp'.jpg

Is such a naming not possible?
Or do I have an error?

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible. But you have provided insufficient information for me to be certain what the issue is. But I can see some potential issues.

```
get_feature(
'ueber_ent_kon_034e0ec4_8f93_4674_80d1_91b5d3ce8671',
'uuid',"kon_uuid" )
```

In your original post, I can't see that the layer 'ueber_ent_kon' has an attribute 'kon_uuid'. SHould this be 'uuid'.

Also, I think you are using attribute(), where is should be attributes(), i.e.

```
attributes(get_feature(...))['kz_anlage']
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's annoying when you spend time to answer a question and the author can't be bothered to respond or vote.